# How to print an array while reading a file

Tags: c++, arrays, file, numbers, ifstream

I am reading from a txt file which has 25 numbers in it, five for each line.

```
1 8 5 7 9
2 4 6 8 10
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 3
```

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string myFile, mystring;
string DIR;
string extension;
int total = 0;

int number_of_lines = 0;
string line;

extension = ".txt";
DIR = "H:\\Year2\\C++\\EE273\\Week5\\";

cout << "Enter the name of the file ";
cin >> myFile;

myFile = DIR + myFile + extension;
ifstream inFile;

inFile.open(myFile.c_str());

if (!inFile) {
    cout <<"Error opening file"<<myFile<<endl;
    return -1;
}

while (!inFile.eof()){  

        int m=5;
        int n=5;
        int Array[i][j];

        for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
            for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
                inFile >> Array[i][j];
                    for(int row=0;row<5;row++){
                        for (int column=0;column<5;column++){
                        cout<<Array[i][j];
                        }}}}
}

    //cout<<mystring<<endl;
inFile.close();
system("PAUSE");

}
```

and the error I get is:

```
error C2065 for i and j: identifier not declared.
```

I can't understand what the problem is.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change line:

```
    int Array[i][j];
```

to:

```
    int Array[5][5];
```

Whole code (i dont have compiller but maybe You want to receive something like this)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string myFile, mystring;
    string DIR;
    string extension;
    int total = 0;

    int number_of_lines = 0;
    string line;

    extension = ".txt";
    DIR = "H:\\Year2\\C++\\EE273\\Week5\\";

    cout << "Enter the name of the file ";
    cin >> myFile;

    myFile = DIR + myFile + extension;
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open(myFile.c_str());

    if (!inFile) {
        cout <<"Error opening file"<<myFile<<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    while (!inFile.eof()){  
        int m=5;
        int n=5;
        int Array[5][5];

        for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
            for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
                inFile >> Array[i][j];
            }
        }
        for(int row=0;row<5;row++){
            for (int column=0;column<5;column++){
                cout << Array[row][column] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Now the program works but the output is wrong. Instead of printing the 25 numbers in the same format as the txt file.. Like each number is printed 20 times

Answer (score 0):

```
int m=5;
int n=5;
int Array[i][j]; // This will raise an error
```

You can try my following code. I have fixed the above code and moved int Array[5][5] out of the scope of the while (!inFile.eof()). I also moved

```
       for (int row = 0; row<5; row++){
            for (int column = 0; column<5; column++){
                cout << Array[row][column] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
```

out of the scope of the while (!inFile.eof()). This was the reason why the output was repeated.

I tested the modified code and it produced the correct output:

1 8 5 7 9
2 4 6 8 10
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string myFile, mystring;
    string DIR;
    string extension;
    int total = 0;

    int number_of_lines = 0;
    string line;

    extension = ".txt";
     DIR = "H:\\Year2\\C++\\EE273\\Week5\\";

    cout << "Enter the name of the file ";
    cin >> myFile;

    myFile = DIR + myFile + extension;
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open(myFile.c_str());

    if (!inFile) {
        cout << "Error opening file" << myFile << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int Array[5][5];

    while (!inFile.eof()){

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                inFile >> Array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row<5; row++){
        for (int column = 0; column<5; column++){
            cout << Array[row][column] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    inFile.close();
    system("PAUSE");
}
```